# TextView how-to?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

So I have an textView and need to have the same control over it as a regular textField.
I am quite new to iPhone-programming so please be nice to me. :)

What I need is functions like:
textFieldDidBeginEditing
textFieldDidEndEditingWithoutText

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` has a `delegate` (`UITextViewDelegate`), which responds to begin/end of editing, text changes etc.

Just look up in the docs, it has complete information. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I did and what do you know... a delegate and everything stars working. Well I added this to viewDidLoad: textViewName.delegate = self;